# Help with understanding a proof about spherical trigonometry

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, triangles, spheres, spherical-trigonometry

I was reading the book "Foundations of Hyperbolic manifolds" by J. Ratcliffe, where I found the cosine formula for a geodesic triangle on the sphere. The result is as follows:

> If $x, y, z \in \mathbb{S}^2$ are non-collinear points, and we consider a geodesic triangle formed by these points as the vertices with side lengths $a, b,$ and $c$, and opposite angles $\alpha, \beta$, and $\gamma$, then
> $$\cos \alpha = \frac{\cos a - \cos b \cdot \cos c}{\sin b \sin c}.$$

Now, the proof goes as follows:

Consider geodesics $\sigma_1: \left[ 0, a \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$, $\sigma_2: \left[ 0, b \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$, and $\sigma_3: \left[ 0, c \right] \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ such that $\sigma_1 \left( 0 \right) = \sigma_3 \left( c \right) = y, \sigma_2 \left( 0 \right) = \sigma_1 \left( a \right) = z$ and $\sigma_3 \left( 0 \right) = \sigma_2 \left( b \right) = x$. Let the angles be as follows: $\theta \left( \sigma_1' \left( 0 \right), - \sigma_2' \left( b \right) \right) = \alpha$, $\theta \left( \sigma_2' \left( 0 \right),  - \sigma_3' \left( c \right) \right) = \beta$, and $\theta \left( \sigma_3' \left( 0 \right), - \sigma_1' \left( a
\right) \right) = \gamma$. That is, we are in the situation as shown in the figure.

[image]

We now focus on the point $x$. We will assume that $\alpha$ is an acute angle (as given in the book). With this, we consider the vectors $x \times y$ and $z \times x$, where $\times$ denotes the cross product on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since both these vectors are perpendicular to $x$ (by definition of cross-product), and $\sigma_3' \left( 0 \right)$ and $-\sigma_2' \left( b \right)$ are perpendicular to $x$ since they are tangent to the sphere, we have that all four vectors are coplanar.

Now, the author writes that we are in the following situation:

[image]

While it is understood that $\theta \left( \sigma_1' \left( 0 \right), x \times y \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\theta \left( -\sigma_2' \left( b \right), z \times x \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, due to some geometric arguments, what is unclear to me is that why do $x \times y$ and $z \times x$ are on the "opposite sides"? That is, why can such a thing not happen?

[image]

Also, what happens if $\alpha$ is not an acute angle? Any insights into this are appreciated!

Comment: Your third figure looks the good one compared to the second one : does the author meant $x \times z$ instead of $z \times x$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: There was a notational error. Now I have changed it. Do you still think the second figure is the correct one? And why do you think so?

Comment: No, you haven't well read my comment : I (still) maintain that it is your figure (the last one) which is the good one. Besides, if $\alpha$ is not an acute angle, the formula should remain valid.

Comment: @JeanMarie: That is the issue! I am not able to understand how the placements of these vectors will be. Why do you say that the second diagram is the better one? Can you provide me with a geometric reason/hint to conclude it?

Comment: I will attempt in some hours 1) to make a precise 3D drwing 2) to find back, in my documents, another geometrical approach (there are many different ways to establish the formula, for example [this one](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/71fa/abe797bca4e9186b2cec08f1801ea6281831.pdf))

Comment: I have found back the document : see the very nice graphical proof page 325 (which is page 319 in fact) of the very famous book "Mathematics For The Million" [here](https://archive.org/details/HogbenMathematicsForTheMillion/page/n325/mode/2up?view=theater), a 1936 book !

Comment: @JeanMarie: Thank you for the other references! However, it seems that my question was not communicated properly. I meant to ask that in this particular proof (that I have showcased above), why is the final diagram made the way it is made? I am unable to see the cross-product geometry in the proof.